# How does this code form a z-shape with for loops?

Tags: java, for-loop

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numTiles = 8;
        for(int i=0; i<numTiles;i++){
            for(int j=0; j<numTiles;j++){
                if(i==0 || i==numTiles-1){
                    System.out.print("1");  
                }else if (i+j==numTiles-1){
                    System.out.print("1");              
                }else{
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }               
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

I see that it starts off with a for loop that repeats depending on the value of numTiles.  Then the second for loop repeats 8 times and prints out 8 1s. I do not understand the else-if and the else in the for-loop.

If I could get clarification on the else-if and else conditionals it would be appreciated.

Comment: Step through the code with a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`i` represents the row index, while `j` represents the columns.

- The `if` prints the top and bottom rows.
- The `else if` prints the diagonal, as it's equivalent to the linear function `x + y = c` (only where `x,y` are `i,j`).

Consider the following equivalent code in Javascript, where I switched the print inside the `else if` to the digit `2`:

```js
let numTiles = 8;
for (let i = 0; i < numTiles; i++) {
  let row = "";
  for (let j = 0; j < numTiles; j++) {
    if (i == 0 || i == numTiles - 1) {
      row += "1";
    } else if (i + j == numTiles - 1) {
      row += "2";
    } else {
      row += " ";
    }
  }
  console.log(row + '\n');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`i` is the row number and `j` is the column number. (This is true because the `println` only happens when `i` increments, not `j`.)

When `i==0`, you're on the top row, and when `i==numTiles-1`, you're on the bottom row. Thus, the first `if` statement prints the top and bottom horizontal lines of the Z.

When `i+j==numTiles-1`, you're on the main diagonal. Thus, the second `if` statement prints the diagonal line of the Z.

Since a Z is just a top and bottom horizontal line and a diagonal line, together, those print all of it.